# código de error no encontrado python

Tags: python

Estoy usando este código para evitar múltiples líneas en discord pero no funciona

¿Alguien podría ayudarme? Muchísimas gracias

```
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    import datetime
     
    from urllib import parse, request
    import re
     bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="ayuda bot") #Comando
bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help
       
     @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == bot.user:
            return
            if len(message.content) > 120:
            #do stuff here
    
           
        
    bot.run('')
```

Lo que quiero esque no pasen estas cosas en mi discord:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando esto ocurra el bot lo auto elimine

Comment: ¿Dónde falla? ¿En que falla? ¿Cual debe ser el resultado correcto?

Comment: Me aparece un error en bot.run("") y no puedo ejecutar bien el codigo: aquí dejo una captura: https://i.imgur.com/aNIiryL.png

Comment: deberias mostrar alguna captura del error que te arroja porque si no no podemos ayudarte

Comment: hay deje una captura: https://i.imgur.com/aNIiryL.png , aqui dejo otra del error: https://i.imgur.com/6bcuQW6.png

Comment: El código que publicas está mal indentado. No ejecuta.

Comment: Por que esto `if len(message.content) > 120:` está dentro de este if `if message.author == bot.user:`?. Eso haría que tu código se ejecute solo si el usuario que escribió el texto es el bot. Sin embargo hay un return antes. Y una vez un return se ejecuta, el código que viene despues no se ejecuta.

Comment: de aqui obtuve el codigo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67369496/checking-message-length-with-discord-py por alguna razon no funciona  queria comprobar la longitud de lineas que mandan x  mi discord

Comment: Pasa que lo copiaste literalmente como lo ofrece la respuesta. Ese comentario dentro del segundo if quiere decir "acá poné el código que desees". Y ahí el segundo if está fuera del primer if. Por cierto, mi respuesta te sirvió? si no te sirvió, por que?

Comment: Si, si me sirvio muchas gracias ya te vote

Comment: Me alegro, gracias! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explicación

Tu error se debe a que por alguna razón Python cree que no hay nada dentro de tu if a pesar de los comentarios. Hice un código de prueba y a mi me pasa lo mismo.
Al parecer, Python no considera los comentarios como parte del código del if (o de la funcion, while, for, etc).

#### Solución

Coloca algo dentro del if que no sea un comentario. Algo que puedes colocar durante el periodo de prueba de tu bot es `pass`. Pass no hace nada, pero sirve para evitar este tipo de errores sin necesidad de poner código productivo en el if (o whiles, fors, funciones, etc):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
 
from urllib import parse, request
import re
 bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="ayuda bot") #Comando
 bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help
   
 @bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if len(message.content) > 120:
        #do stuff here
        pass

bot.run('')
```

#### Como puedes agregar código en tus preguntas

Por lo que vi en las imagenes que pasaste, tu código está bien indentado, cosa que no pasa en la pregunta. Y como sabes, la indentacion en Python es importante. Para colocar codigo formateado en una pregunta de SO, puedes pegar el código en la pregunta, seleccionarlo todo y presionar las {} arriba de la caja de texto. Al menos a mi nunca me falla eso.